# Find two consecutive natural numbers whose cubes differ by 61

Tags: natural-numbers, quadratics

Find two consecutive natural numbers whose cubes differ by 61. what the quadratic equation?

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy to be honest.

You start from:
[image].

Expanding (x+1)^3 and reducing the equation to normal form you get:
[image],
which is a simple quadratic equation you should be able to solve (otherwise look it up on your book or here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticEquation.html).

This is the graph of the equation.

[image]

Edit: I've just seen you asked a few questions on problems involving quadratic equations, so this is an unrequested advice for you: re-read you coursebook (both "theory" and worked problems) and give a shoot to some other problems. Also, you can have a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAdVUXsMQe4 , which seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Let the smaller number be $a$

$\implies 61=(a+1)^3-a^3=3a^2+3a+1$

Can you simplify to form the required Quadratic Equation?

Comment: Considering that OP has just asked 3 quadratic equation questions which you have answered ... perhaps there is more to gain than just spoon-feeding the immediate answer?

Comment: @CalvinLin, please have  a look into the edited version

Comment: Oh, it was a more 'meta' question that came to me, about how to deal with such cases where questions are arising mainly from OP not understanding how to apply a basic concept that (I believe) they are learning. I would disagree that answering all the individual questions is the best way to proceed, esp if there is no response or indication of absorption.